# datatable has no data after filling it from stored procedure - c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to get all the rows from a `stored procedure` in a datatable, I used `sql profiler` and I can see that parameters are going fine and `stored procedure` is resulting in more than 2000 records but the `datatable` I am filling has null and the `datagridview` gives me `null exception` because its datasource is that datatable.

```
public static DataTable GetJobDetails(string p1, string p1, string p3)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sd;
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetDetails", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = p1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = p2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = p3;

            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sd.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
}
```

and my `datagridview` code is

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = HondaBL.GetJobDetails(p1, p2, p3);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Here is my simple `Stored Procedure`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetDetails] 

@p1 varchar(25),
@p2 varchar(100),
@p3 varchar(25)

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT somefield1, somefield2, somefield3, somefield4, somefield5
    FROM mytable
    WHERE p1= @p1
          AND p2= @p2
          AND p3= @p3

END
```

I ran the query and I am getting from `sql profiler` and it shows me result which is more than 2000 rows.

Comment: and `usp_GetDetails` is returning rows? Please share that stored procedure.

Comment: When is Your DT still NULL ? After dt = HondaBL.GetJobDetails(); ???

Comment: I never used Fill to a `DataTable`, only a `DataSet`. However, correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't it require that the `TableName` matches? I believe the `DataTable` must be associated with a `DataSet` for this to work the way you're using it.

Comment: @dman2306 No, you can fill a DT directly.  A DS is just a nice container when you have many tables

Comment: @Plutonix you're sure? The MSDN article makes it sound like that's not the case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx "Adds or refreshes rows in a specified range **in the DataSet** to match those in the data source using the DataTable name."

Comment: Look at the argument for the method (in the title): **DataTable**

Comment: @Plutonix yes, but a `DataTable` has a `DataSet` property because it keeps track of what `DataSet` it belongs to. In his example, that would have to be `null`. Based on the MSDN article, you can't do that. It could be a very poorly worded article, but it sounds to me like it has to be associated with a `DataSet` to work.

Comment: @rene I have updated my question with Stored Procedure

Comment: Try it - it works fine.  You dont even need a DataAdapater:  `myDt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())` also works

Comment: @icbytes `dt` is null when I am filling it at `sd.Fill(dt);`

Comment: @Plutonix you can directly fill the `datatable`, I have a same logic for my other  `datagridview` and that is working fine

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui I know, it is dman that thinks not (and sorry for hijacking the comments).

Comment: What is the stacktrace? Is one of the parameters you supply null?

Comment: @Plutonix same `exception` with `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())`, `datatable` is still null

Comment: @rene: no all parameters are not null, they have values

Comment: Null and Empty are not the same thing. This code cannot give back a NULL datatable in any case. But it could return an empty datatable. How do you discover the DataTable is  ''null'? By the way you could write just 
_dataGridView1.DataSource = HondaBL.GetJobDetails(p1, p2, p3);_

Comment: while debugging I saw `sd.Fill(dt);` here datatable is empty and returned empty datatable when I called the `data layer` method

Comment: Either you pass a datatable directky to the DataSource member or You pass a dataset conaining at least one table and the table by name to DataMember

Comment: If the datatable is empty then the value of your parameters applied to the WHERE clause inside the stored procedure produce an emtpy resultset. Also, if your fields are of type nvarchar use the appropriate _SqlDbType.NVarChar_

Comment: @Steve I used sql profiler and I got this query `exec usp_GetDetails @p1='somedata',@p2='somedata',@p3='somedata'` and it gives me more than 2000 records when I execute

Comment: What is the return value of `sd.Fill(dt)`?

Comment: I am getting all the data in datatable now but my datagridview shows empty window.

Comment: Is the `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `true`?

Comment: if the datatable has data but it doesnt show in the DGV, you might have  `DataPropertyName` values set which do not exist in that DT

Comment: I figured it out, I was calling this method to bind in `datagridview` from one form to another form and I was calling Parametrized Constructor to send some data[p1, p2, p3] to other form, but I wasn't initializing the components in that Parametrized Constructor., once I initialized components, BOOM, everything fixed!
Thanks for brainstorming with me..